# Script Remove All hardlinks for a specific file

Tags: scripts, hard-link

I want to delete all hardlinks for a specific file.

The usage would be `script somefile`, this would count the hardlinks for the file somefile, then it's going to delete all hardlinks keeping this file only.

The command

```
find / -samefile file-name | xargs rm
```

will do  the needed but this deletes the original file also.

Also you can use

```
find / -inum Inode-number | xargs rm
```

But this also would delete the original file.

My first script veriosn looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
inode=`ls -li $file | cut -d" " -f1`

find / -inum $inode | xargs rm
```

But as I said above this would delete the original file also, so how to keep the first instance and remove others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `!` with the path to the original file to exclude it:

```
$ find . -samefile bar                   
./baz
./bar
$ find . -samefile bar ! -path "./bar"   
./baz
```

The path must match what `find` outputs, so use absolute paths if you search from `/`.

Notes:

- `find` has a `-delete` command
- If combining with `xargs`, use `-print0` and `-0`:

  ```
  find  . -samefile bar ! -path "./bar" -print0 | xargs -0 rm
  ```
- Use `stat` to get the inode number directly:

  ```
  $ stat -c '%i' bar
  257643
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This works for both absolute and relative filenames plus it doesn't print any "Permission denied" dialogs and prints `Deletion failed: <filename>` when deleting fails:

```
find / -samefile "$1" \! -path "${PWD}/$1" \! -delete -printf 'Deletion failed: %p\n' 2>/dev/null
```